# Get Control Panel Device C++

Tags: c++, windows, device-driver, device, device-manager

I'm trying to write some code which will fetch all the information from my computer's device manager.

I have the following code:

```
HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
DWORD i;
// Create a HDEVINFO with all present devices.
hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL,0,0,DIGCF_PRESENT|DIGCF_ALLCLASSES );
// Enumerate through all devices in Set.
DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
for (i=0;SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo,i,&DeviceInfoData);i++)
{
    DWORD DataT;
    LPTSTR buffer = NULL;
    DWORD buffersize = 200;
    buffer = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR,buffersize);
    SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData, SPDRP_DEVICEDESC, &DataT,(PBYTE)buffer,buffersize,&buffersize);
    printf("Result:[%s]\n", buffer);

    if (buffer) 
        LocalFree(buffer);
}
// Cleanup
SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
```

But to be honest, that's not what I'm looking for, because the list I'm getting lacks the details which the control panel has.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain the information you're looking for versus what you're receiving?

Comment: Sure. Chipset, Cpu, Gpu, and I would also like know if my hdd is sata or ssd.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong technology. Try WMI. `SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor` for CPU information (you weren't specific which CPU information you wanted), `SELECT VideoProcessor FROM Win32_VideoController` for GPU information, and `SELECT InterfaceType FROM Win32_DiskDrive` for disk information.